# .BAT Copying file - same directory different drive

Tags: batch-file

How would i go about writing a .bat file, so that i can drag and drop a file onto it in windows 7, that would copy the file to the same directory, but on a different drive?

So if my file was:

```
D:\Files\Newfiles\File01.jpg
```

It would copy it to a prespecified network location (COMPUTER_01):

```
\\COMPUTER_01\Files\Newfiles\File01.jpg
```

I've looked into using command line parameters %~p1 and %~nx1, but i'm not sure how these would be implemented.

I'm sure this is painfully easy to do but I have no idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Painfully easy it is:

```
copy %1 "\\COMPUTER_01%~p1"
```